# iOS Apps & Subscriptions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

Am I *required* to use Apple's In-App Purchase support if I wish to allow for subscriptions in my app?  I'm currently working on an app that will be free to download and use.  It will be ad-supported, but I will also offer a premium version of the service that won't display ads.  Can I implement the subscription functionality myself within the app/backend service  (Registration, credit card processing, etc.)?  Or, am I required to use Apple's In-App Purchase support (thereby also giving up 30% of my subscription fee)

Comment: You cannot use anything for in-app purchases other than Apple's IAP APIs (pun intended). Your app will almost certainly be rejected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are required. Apple will reject anything that tries to work around their 30% cut

Answer (score 4):

Actually... there is a workaround where you may keep 100% of the revenue:

"If you would like to make a subscription offer outside of the app, the same (or better) subscription price must be offered inside the app for users who wish to subscribe from within the app."
Source: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/subscriptions.html

Not sure if this speaks directly to your question of making an app ad free, but it is possible to keep 100% of the revenue IF you make the same offer as an in app purchase.

Apple reversed these guidelines a while ago, allowing devs to mark up in-app purchases, but I am not sure if this is still relevant.

See: http://www.macworld.com/article/1160430/apple_removes_pricing_restrictions_in_app_subscriptions.html

and

http://help.rdio.com/customer/portal/questions/433219-price-discrepancy

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said you are required to use original Apple APIs. Moreover, according to Apple’s policy a developer can not choose which type of In-App-Purchases to use for their apps. You can read more about it in a dev's post

[iOS In-App Purchase Overview: Our Hands-On Experience](http://blog.azoft.com/ios-in-app-purchases/)

In brief there are 3 types of subscriptions:

- **free** -- are used by applications that offer issues for free
- **auto-renewable** -- after the first successful purchase, they are
  prolonging themselves automatically if users’ credit card is valid
  and if he hasn't stopped it manually
- **non-renewing** -- subscription is initiated by users, lasts a certain
  period of time and stops when the period ends, to subscribe again, a
  user should initiate the    subscription manually.

  The use of auto-renewable subscription **is limited only to Mass Media** category applications. Free subscription can't be used for demo versions distributed with commercial purposes. And certainly, if an app violates Apple's requirements on In-App Purchase use and limitations, it will be banned from AppStore.